# Other than for nobel prizes, is there some award's/prize's linked data available?

Tags: linked-data

Other than for nobel prizes, is there some award's/prize's linked data/rdf/schema available?

Comment: Can you add more detail, perhaps what type of prizes or awards you are looking for or how it might be used? That detail helps people find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

1) Take a look at [Wikipedia's list of prizes, medals and awards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prizes,_medals_and_awards).

2) Searching through the list of different awards (and awarded people) could pave the way to find an interesting category, for example [Fukuoka Asian Culture Prize winners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fukuoka_Asian_Culture_Prize_winners).

3) Then go to the [DBpedia SPARQL endopoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and extract all awarded persons like in this example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?awarded WHERE {
 ?x dcterms:subject category:Fukuoka_Asian_Culture_Prize_winners
}
```

Hope this helps.